# Rails ActiveRecord and array of primitive types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best way to store array of of primitive types using Rails activerecord?

For example I've got article model, which has images property. Images property is array of image urls.

I don't wont use separate table to store this array.

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Base.serialize](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/Base.serialize). It will save the object as YAML in database. You need to first create the column with `:text` or `:string` as its type.

```
class Article
  serialize :image_urls
end

article.image_urls = ['/images/image1.png', '/images/image2.png']
```

Comment: Great! I've dreamed about such feature when using asp.net mvc :)